# Cannot get correct immediate mode from GNU assembler for symbols with intel_syntax

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I am trying to write a simple assembly program with GNU assembler (as) in MAC OS. Part of the program looks like the following:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.globl _main
.text
...
   mov   rdx, len
   syscall
   ...
.data
message: .asciz "this is a message!\n"
len = . - message
```

After assembly and link, the executable code viewed in the debugger is:

```
   movq  0x14, %rdx
   syscall
```

But what I really want is `movq $0x14, %rdx` instead of `movq 0x14, %rdx`

I tried to put the `.data` section before the `.text` section but still getting the same result.

How can I get the correct immediate mode with intel syntax?

Comment: Try `mov rdx, $len`.

Comment: Duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355188/distinguishing-memory-from-constant-in-gnu-as-intel-syntax

Comment: Moving the `.data` stuff before `.text`, including the `len = ` line, works for me.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, but all the following 3 modifications fail to solve the problem:1. Moving the `.data` before `.text` => Did not work
2. Using instruction `mov rdx, OFFSET len` => resulted in assembly error `error: cannot use more than one symbol in memory operand`
3. Using instruction `mov rdx, $len` => also resulted in assembly error `error: unknown token in expression`