# Constant (.equ) in asm

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

Let's say I define a constant such as the following in asm:

```
.data
SYS_EXIT = 60

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $SYS_EXIT,  %eax
   syscall
```

Does the assembler literally do the equivalent of a 'find-replace' at run-time to replace the value of `SYS_EXIT` with `60`? In other words, the program becomes the following after substitution?

```
.text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $60,  %eax
   syscall
```

If so, does it make a difference 'where' I define the `SYS_EXIT` variable? For example, does it need to go in a particular section, and if not, what is the convention of where to put it? For example:

```
.data
SYS_EXIT = 60

------------------------

.rodata
SYS_EXIT = 60

------------------------

(start of file)
SYS_EXIT = 60
```

Finally (perhaps a separate question), is there a way to view all constants in `gdb`? I can view the manually by knowing the label, but not in doing something like `info va`:

```
>>> info va
All defined variables: [empty]
>>> p/d &SYS_EXIT
$1 = 60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a numeric value substitution, not a text substitution, but basically yes.

re: definition order, see [Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel_syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39355188) - with `$SYS_EXIT` in AT&T syntax there's no ambiguity even if the constant is defined later.  With `.intel_syntax` it can matter whether a constant is defined before or after an instruction that uses it.

(These are *not* like C preprocessor macros, they're more like labels; you can reference later definitions from earlier code, like normal for assembler.)

And no, assemble-time constants don't have a section.  Switching to a section just to use a `foo = number` directive is misleading, don't do it.

---

Values defined with `=` do appear in the symbol table of object files, like other symbols.  (That's why you can see it with GDB or `nm`).  If you use `.globl` they'll be visible for use in other files, like label addresses are.

I'm not sure if that's useful for anything; it's probably best to `.include` a file of definitions for constants if you want to use them across files, rather than letting the linker fill them in.

I don't know why GDB's `va` didn't show them; probably because they don't have a `.type` marking them as variables.

Comment: Technically, they are in the absolute section.  Which is to say, they aren't in any section.