# Why would I use NASM over GNU Assembler (GAS)?

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu, gnu-assembler

Why would I use NASM over GNU Assembler (GAS) when GAS supports multiple architectures whereas NASM supports the x86 architecture exclusively? I know that there are syntactic differences, but that doesn't bother me too much.

Comment: It is just a matter of taste. But the real question is *why would use use any assembler* since compilers (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) can embed `asm` statement? In 2020, assembler code is usually *generated*. You could compile some `foo.c` with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O2 -S foo.c` and look into the generated `foo.s`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm learning assembly

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So you want me to email you the reasons im interested in assembler/ly?

Comment: Yes, because in 2020 it is 95% of the time a loss of your developer time. It is more effective to use [`asm` statements with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html), e.g. to mix a few `asm` statements in your C code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can tell you the reasons right here: I want to understand how the CPU works mire in-depth. I want to understand how memory works. I would like to read the Linux Kernel source code and am interested in memory hacking.

Comment: But [the Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/) (or [musl-libc](http://musl.libc.org/), or [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)...) is coded in C mostly

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch there is still some assembler code in it. I am also interested in writing my own OS and programming embedded systems.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch plus, it's interesting

Comment: Then see also [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/).... For embedded systems, consider [Arduino](https://arduino.cc/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: *understanding* assembly language is still useful for understanding  performance, and CPU architecture (design decisions that CPU designers make).  I don't actually spend time *writing* production code in assembler, just microbenchmarks, but I know asm and CPUs quite well.  (For fun and profit.)  I don't see the point in writing a 16-bit bootloader or DOS program myself when it would just talk to emulated legacy hardware, but I got my bare-metal experience on Atari ST back in the late 90s before getting a PC to run Linux on.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch damn... thanks a lot!!! ive been searching for something like that for ages.

Comment: @PeterCordes: So do I. But the last time I wrote some assembler code was in the previous century

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I typically write asm in my head and then type C or C++ SIMD intrinsics to get the compiler to emit something close to what I was thinking of.  Sometimes compilers make it hard to get them to emit asm as efficient as I'd like, then I either file a missed optimization bug report or add it to the TODO list pile of things to get back to...

Comment: @Serket: added some more points in NASM's favour, especially %rep / `times` are relevant for convenient experimentation / microbenchmarking.

Comment: Writing assembly is lots of fun!  I can really recommend it.

Comment: I think it's better to isolate assembly away from C code and use inline assembly only where necessary as compilers can sometimes play around with your assembly and mess it up

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ASM is inherently non-portable.  Only the GAS directives are the same for other ISAs (not instructions or even comment character), and any given asm source file will be for a single ISA.  GAS itself supporting multiple targets is not really relevant, you still have to learn other machines.  (Which is not hard to pick up at least the basics once you know one, but directive syntax differences are generally even easier).  Some other assemblers for other ISAs use NASM-style `db` and `dd` data pseudo-instructions, others use Unix-style `.byte` and `.long` like GAS (or *are* GAS).  But that's very easy to adapt to.

GAS was first designed to assemble compiler output; as such its error messages aren't always wonderful for human usage.  (In terms of clarity about what exactly it doesn't like about a line).  NASM tends to be better (but by no means perfect), and modern GAS is generally not bad either; some major projects (like glibc and Linux) have hand-written GAS source files so there certainly is human use of it.

NASM has a macro language (https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html) that in some ways is easier to use for complex stuff than [GAS's `.macro` macros](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html).  (Although it's common to use CPP macros with GAS).

**For microbenchmarking** (one of the few reasons to play around with asm by hand these days), NASM has a features that I don't know how to do as easily in GAS: **`times`** to repeat one line.  **`%rep`** to repeat a block is also useful.  GAS's `.rept` can do that, but if you want to vary the block (e.g. to unroll and do `[rdi+0]` / `[rdi+4]` / ...), NASM is nicer. In GAS you can use a recursive macro that calls itself with a smaller arg, but NASM allows `%assign` to implement a counter inside a `%rep`.

```
    times 10  imul eax,eax        ; repeat this line 10 times

 %rep 10                       ; repeat this block 10 times
    add  eax, ecx
    add  ecx, eax
 %endrep
```

NASM has very nice syntax for multi-character constants as numbers, e.g. `mov rax, 'abcdefgh'` / `push rax` results in those 8 ASCII characters on the stack in source order.  GAS can't do anything equivalent; you need to use raw numbers or stuff like `'h'<<56 | 'g'<<48 | ...`

NASM can assemble a flat binary without needing the complication of a linker + linker script.  Mostly only relevant for 16-bit bootloaders, but possibly shellcode.

Until recently, GAS had some bad stuff like `add [rdi], 1234` silently defaulting to dword operand size, instead of warning you that it's ambiguous for instructions other than `mov`.  Recent GAS has fixed that; now it's an error just like in NASM.  (In AT&T mode, GAS just warns, but in Intel-syntax mode it's an error.)

---

**NASM's syntax is 100% consistent about `[]` - brackets present *always* means a memory operand**, not present means *never* a memory operand.  (Just to be clear about what I mean, LEA takes a memory operand but doesn't load from it.)  AT&T syntax is also easy to distinguish (`$` or not is the difference between immediate or memory), but **GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` depends on how a symbol was declared**.  `add eax, foobar` could be `add eax, imm32` or `add eax, [disp32]`.  Even worse, it depends whether `foobar` was declared with an `equ` or `=` before or after the instruction that uses it, unless you use `OFFSET` even if you're later doing `foobar = 42`!!!  [Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel_syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355188/distinguishing-memory-from-constant-in-gnu-as-intel-syntax).

Intel syntax is NASM's primary and only mode, so you can easily look up instructions in Intel's or AMD's manuals.  `.intel_syntax noprefix` is a secondary feature for GAS, not as well documented as its AT&T.  It does work decently except for the above ambiguity.

And sometimes GNU tools even in Intel-syntax mode (like `objdump -d -Mintel`) still follow the AT&T syntax bug swapping of some forms of x87 instructions like fdiv vs. fdivr.  If you ever want to use x87, avoid GAS if you can.  See [9.16.17 AT&T Syntax bugs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dBugs.html) in the GAS manual.  I think modern objdump might "get this right" now, but if I was only using GAS + binutils I wouldn't have something I trusted not to be corrupted by stupid AT&T implementation bugs that GAS had to be bug-compatible with.  Totally irrelevant outside of x87 instructions, so fortunately irrelevant most of the time now.

Comment: That about covers it all from an overview standpoint. I'm glad you touched on NASM's macro feature. That is often overlooked but extremely handy for small tasks. Always educational answers.