# Symbol defined after statment its used on, so it's assumed to be an external symbol

Tags: assembly, x86, att, gnu-assembler

I am converting some code from Intel Syntax to AT&T syntax.

I have the folowing code, that loads a GDT, and does a far jump using the loaded GDT, defined in the `.rodata` section.

```
.global start
.extern long_mode_start

.section .text
start:
        lgdt    (gdt64.pointer)
        jmp     $gdt64.code, $long_mode_start
```

```
.section .rodata
gdt64:
        .quad 0 # zero entry
.equ gdt64.code, 0x08
        .quad (1<<43) | (1<<44) | (1<<47) | (1<<53) # code segment
gdt64.pointer:
        .word . - gdt64 - 1
        .quad gdt64
```

The problem is that I have to put the `.rodata` section before the `.text` section on the file, otherwise the assembler complains: `` Error: can't handle non absolute segment in `jmp' ``, which makes me think that it's assuming it is an external symbol, even though I didn't say so.

Is there any way to make this work with the `.rodata` section in any place in the file, or does it really have to be before the `.text` section?

Comment: GNU assembler assumes symbols are external by default (incidentally that means the `.extern long_mode_start` is not required). You do not need to move the `.rodata` section, only the `.equ gdt64.code, 0x08` which is not part of a section since it is just an assembler directive.

Comment: @Jester What if I had ```.equ gdt64.code, . - gdt64``` on the ```.rodata``` section? I hat to move the whole section right?

Comment: Yes, because `.` refers to the current position which does depend on the location.

Comment: Even if you replace the `.` with a symbol, the assembler needs to see it first, according to my tests.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: Highly related: [Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel\_syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39355188) including an AT&T syntax section at the end.  (With a different use that actually assembles either way so we can see what the assembler was thinking.)  Assuming you want to keep the `0x08` constant definition next to the other parts of `.rodata` just for maintenance reasons, yes, it seems you need to move it ahead of the code that uses it.