# Inconsistency in addressing mode? Why would you use $foo on a .equ value defined in another file?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, gnu-assembler

I'm reading the book Learn to program with Assembly by Jonathan Bartlett. I'm in chapter 7 on Data Record.The author introduces structs and records in Assembly. He created a simple record of a person in the file personsdata.s, where there is an array of 6 people and their characteristics: weight, hair colour, height and age.

```
persondata.s
.section .data
.globl people, numpeople
numpeople:
    # Calculate the number of people in array
    .quad (endpeople - people)/PERSON_RECORD_SIZE
people:
    # Array of people
    .quad 200, 2, 74, 20
    .quad 280, 2, 72, 44 # me!
    .quad 150, 1, 68, 30
    .quad 250, 3, 75, 24
    .quad 250, 2, 70, 11
    .quad 180, 5, 69, 65
endpeople: # Marks the end of the array for calculation purposes
# Describe the components of the struct
.globl WEIGHT_OFFSET, HAIR_OFFSET, HEIGHT_OFFSET, AGE_OFFSET
.equ WEIGHT_OFFSET, 0
.equ HAIR_OFFSET, 8
.equ HEIGHT_OFFSET, 16
.equ AGE_OFFSET, 24

# Total size of the struct
.globl PERSON_RECORD_SIZE
.equ PERSON_RECORD_SIZE, 32
```

This file is only about this data record. At the end of this file there is constant PERSON_RECORD_SIZE which described what is the size in bytes of a single person is array. It's later used in a loop to go to the next person, specifically to its height. He created the program that returns a biggest height value.- tallest.s

```
tallest.s
.globl _start
.section .text
_start:
    ### Initialize Registers ###
    # Pointer to first record
    leaq people, %rbx
    # Record count
    movq numpeople, %rcx
    # Tallest value found
    movq $0, %rdi
    ### Check Preconditions ###
80Chapter 7
Data Records
    # If there are no records, finish
    cmpq $0, %rcx
    je finish
    ### Main Loop ###
mainloop:
    # %rbx is the pointer to the whole struct
    # This instruction grabs the height field
    # and stores it in %rax
    movq HEIGHT_OFFSET(%rbx), %rax
    # If it is less than or equal to our current
    # tallest, go to the next one.
    cmpq %rdi, %rax
    jbe endloop
    # Copy this value as the tallest value
    movq %rax, %rdi
endloop:
    # Move %rbx to point to the next record
    addq $PERSON_RECORD_SIZE, %rbx
    # Decrement %rcx and do it again
    loopq mainloop
    ### Finish it off ###
finish:
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

I understand everything in this record except one thing. We access the person's height using movq HEIGHT_OFFSET(%rbx), %rax and I understand that, but when it comes to moving to the next person and specifically the person's height, he uses addq $PERSON_RECORD_SIZE, %rbx. And here is my question. If this line is just about adding 32 to rbx to move to the next person and their height value in memory why is it using the $ sign before the constant name. I thought direct memory mode would be appropiraite here. We use it at the beginning movq numpeople, %rcx to move the number of people into the rcx module.

I've put $32 instead of $PERSON_RECORD_SIZE and it works fine. But when I put PERSON_RECORD_SIZE there is a segmentation error. I don't understand this. There seems to be some inconsistency.Is it some other addressing mode that I'm not aware of? (keep in mind I've been learning assembly for a couple of weeks now and I'm not a software engineer on a daily basis).I'm sure it's some detail I'm missing.

Comment: `$` means immediate. `numpeople` is an actual variable that takes space in memory. `PERSON_RECORD_SIZE` is just a "constant", a number not allocated in any section (see `.equ`).

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: How old is this book?  `loopq mainloop` really?  [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35742570) - pretty much never use `loop`.  Oh, published 2021.  Interesting, I'm familiar with the author's name from the free (GFDL) book *Programming from the ground up*, which used 32-bit AT&T syntax for Linux from around 2000.

Comment: this is an updated version of Programming from the ground up

Answer (score 1):

`.equ foo, 32` defines an assemble-time constant, not assembling any bytes in the current section of the output.

Actually it defines a symbol like a `foo:` label would, but "address" `32`, that's why in GAS you're able to export it with `.globl foo` so it's visible to the *linker* in the symbol table of the `.o` file.

`add $foo, %rbx` adds 32, the "value" (aka address) of the symbol.
`add foo, %rbx` would load from absolute address `32`, using the symbol as the address of a memory operand.

In both cases, the symbol "address" becomes part of the machine code of the instruction being assembled, the difference is only whether the opcode is one that uses it as an immediate or as a memory operand.   That's also true if you do `.quad foo` to emit 8 bytes with that value (address).  This applies regardless of whether the symbol address aka value is labeling a position in some section, or is an integer defined with `.equ` or `foo = 123` (alternate syntax for the same thing).

Unfortunately when assembling `add $foo, %rbx`, the assembler doesn't know the value yet (it's only a link-time constant since it's an undefined symbol in this file).  So it picks `add $imm32, %rbx`, making the instruction 3 bytes larger in machine code than `add $32, %rbx` which would see the small value at assemble time and be able to pick the 8-bit immediate encoding.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add).  For this reason, I wouldn't recommend using `.equ` across asm source files.  Use the C preprocessor so you can `#define foo 32` in a `.h` that you `#include` in both files.

(The difference between a symbol labeling an address in some section vs. an absolute constant (section `*UND*`) actually creates ambiguity in GNU assembler `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode, but that applies even for code that uses it earlier in the same source file than the `.equ`, not just across source files: see *[Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel_syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355188/distinguishing-memory-from-constant-in-gnu-as-intel-syntax)*.  There's actually one ambiguity even in AT&T syntax, but only in a corner case that's not useful.)

---

**The "value" of a symbol is its address**.  (A rough analogy is `extern char foo[]`, so writing `foo` is the address, but AT&T syntax dereferences bare symbol names implicitly in instructions; the analogy works better in NASM.)  If there are bytes in memory at that address, you can use the symbol to assemble instructions that will *at runtime* access them, but you can't get the bytes into an immediate embedded in the machine code, or use it to control a `.rept` or anything like that.

Variables are a high-level language concept which you can implement in assembly using labels to define symbols ahead of directives like `.byte` to emit some static storage, such as `bar: .byte 123`.  The symbol `bar` has a "value" which other instructions can refer to at assemble/link time (e.g. to generate a byte-load from 4 bytes later, like `movzbl bar+4(%rip), %eax`).

**An asm source line involving the symbol `foo` will assemble bytes into the output that include the symbol's "address"** (or things based on it, like for relative addressing, or `mov $foo-bar, %eax` for distance between two symbols.)

But you can't make the assembler reference the `123` byte  or any other bytes that happen to be at or near the address the symbol is attached to.  **Access to bytes assembled into the output can only happen at run-time**.  e.g. `.quad bar` emits the 64-bit absolute address, and `.byte bar` tries to fit the absolute address into a byte but will fail at link time (unless you had a linker script that put your .data section in the very bottom of address-space!). If you wanted to avoid repeating yourself and hard-coding `123` in multiple places, you'd need to use an assemble-time constant like `.equ barval, 123` and use that in multiple places, like `.byte barval` in multiple places.

---

### Use RIP-relative addressing

In 64-bit code you'd normally never write `add symbol, %reg`; the 32-bit absolute addressing mode is not efficient or useful for anything except maybe MMIO at some absolute address, not for your own `.data`.  You always want `add symbol(%rip), %reg` [RIP-relative addressing if `symbol` is the address of static storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing).  Using symbol addresses as 32-bit absolute is useful when used with other registers as an array index, as in `add my_array(,%rdx,8), %rax` or something, but see *[32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)* (you can't do that in a PIE executable.)

See also *[Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)* re: x86-64's selection of addressing modes.

And *[How do RIP-relative variable references like "[RIP + _a]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy)* for more detail about the difference in meaning for `foo(%rip)` vs. `123(%rip)`.

Comment: So much information. Thank you :)